# how to send base64 string as response in $http in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send an image as base64 string in response in angularjs but the controller is moving to the error function.

The controller of angularjs is like this

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('showimageCtrl', showcustomimagecontroller);
        showcustomimagecontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
        function showcustomimagecontroller($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                url: '/Home/showimage',
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.image = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                alert('error');
            });
        }
```

The .cshtml view is like this

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>textonimage</title>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/app/controller/myimagectrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="showimageCtrl"> 
        <img width="1000" id="y" src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The jsonresult showimage() in Home controller is like this

```
public JsonResult showimage()
        {
            //creating a image object
            System.Drawing.Image bitmap = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/images/DSC06528.JPG")); // set image 
                                                                                                                         //draw the image object using a Graphics object
            Graphics graphicsImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            //Set the alignment based on the coordinates   
            StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat();
            stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            StringFormat stringformat2 = new StringFormat();
            stringformat2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            stringformat2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            //Set the font color/format/size etc..  
            Color StringColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#933eea");//direct color adding
            Color StringColor2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e80c88");//customise color adding
            string Str_TextOnImage = "Happy";//Your Text On Image
            string Str_TextOnImage2 = "Onam";//Your Text On Image
            graphicsImage.DrawString(Str_TextOnImage, new Font("arial", 400,
            FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(3000, 545),
            stringformat); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            graphicsImage.DrawString(Str_TextOnImage2, new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", 401,
            FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(StringColor2), new Point(4000, 545),
            stringformat2); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] j= (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(j, 0, j.Length);
            return Json(base64String);
        }
```

I want the angularjs to hit success function and display the image.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: When I am using debugger I am getting this error                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                     
 response = SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Ic (http://localhost:3382/scripts/angular.min.js:16:379) at jc (http://localhost:3382/scripts/angular.min.js:95:289) at http://localhost:3382/scripts/angular.min.js:96:201 at q (http://localhost:3382/scripts/angular

Comment: Can you print the byte64String variable for me please and the results of Json(byte64String)

Comment: seems to be issue with `json` conversion, please try [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript) also. might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `response.data` contains the base64 code of the image. (please comment if otherwise)

You should be using `ng-src` probably

```
<img width="1000" id="y" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}" />
```

Otherwise the `{{image}}` expression will not get bound with `$scope.image` and evaluated by Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're returning the base64-encoded image data directly as a JSON response. It is *not* JSON and can't be decoded as such, hence your error. Instead, you should return something like:

```
return Json(new { image = base64string });
```

This will result in an actual JSON document like:

```
{ "image": "[base64 encoded data]" }
```

You can then access the `image` member of your response data object:

```
$scope.image = response.data.image;
```